# How to get most recent file in a directory without using a FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to write a batch file that returns the most recent file in a directory without using a `for` loop. I tried a lot but it's not working.

So is there a approach that we can get the most recent file without using `for` loop?

```
@echo off  
cd D:\Applications  
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set RECENT="%%~nxi"  
echo ..... starting jar........  
start java -jar %RECENT%  
echo ....jar started.....  
exit 0
```

The execution gets stuck at start java and it does not go to next line or exit 0.

Comment: so if you change `echo ..... starting jar` to `echo ..... starting jar: %RECENT%`, does it show the (correct) file?

Comment: yes it does shows the correct file if i use ... starting jar : %RECENT%

Comment: This answer your _question_, but don't solve your _problem_ (as @Stephan already said): `dir /O:-D /B > file.txt & set /P "RECENT=" < file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be used the following code using command **FOR**:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "D:\Applications" 2>nul || (echo ERROR: Directory D:\Applications does not exist.& goto EndBatch)
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%i in ('dir /A-D /B /O-D /TC 2^>nul') do set "RECENT=%%i" & goto StartJava
echo WARNING: Could not find any file in directory: "%CD%"& goto EndBatch
:StartJava
if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe java.exe >nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 echo ERROR: Could not find java.exe. Check environment variable PATH.& goto EndBatch
echo ..... Starting jar .....
start "Running %RECENT%" java.exe -jar "%RECENT%"
if not errorlevel 1 echo ..... jar started .....
:EndBatch
if errorlevel 1 echo(& pause
endlocal
```

There is some error handling also added to the code.

Please note that the creation date is the date of a file on being created in the current directory. So if a file is copied from directory `X` to directory `Y`, its last modification date is not modified, but the file has a new creation date in directory `Y` which is newer than its last modification date.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `where /?`

See also:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use the most powerful command in `cmd`, but for the sake of answering your question:

```
dir /o-d /b "C:\my folder\*" >tmp
<tmp set /p "latest="
del tmp
echo the latest file is %latest%
```